# How do I link my windows 10 edition of Minecraft to Mojang

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I bought the windows 10 edition of Minecraft and I want to know if I can link that account to Mojang because when I tried using the account I had for the Windows 10 edition they wanted me to buy it again

Comment: did you buy it from the Windows Store?

Comment: Yes I did......

Comment: Do you also have the Mojang/Java Version of Minecraft? (the one not from the Windows Store)

Comment: No, that is what my question is about. I want to know if I can link the Windows version to the Mojang version

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, there is no way to redeem the Java Version of the game with the C++ (Windows 10) Version of the game. You could try writing Mojang (which is now owned by Microsoft) and try to convince them to give you their version, but I doubt that they would agree to that.

For future reference, it does work the other way around though - you can redeem the C++ version via your Mojang Account.